# override backbone.sync only for put

Tags: backbone.js

Is there any possible way to override the sync method for `PUT` response and exclude the `id` field from db, and remaining the same? I am using the Django REST framework for APIs; while trying to `PUT`, I'm getting:

```
{"field_errors": "id": ["This field does not exist."],}
```

I think if I override sync and exclude the `id` field for `PUT`, my problem will be solved, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: if your problem is the url you can modify the default [Collection.url](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-url) and/or [Model.urlRoot](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-urlRoot) default behaviors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Backbone._sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
var params = _.clone(options);
delete model.attributes.id;
params.success = function(model) {
    if(options.success) options.success(model);
};
params.error = function(model) {
    if(options.error) options.error(model);
    };
Backbone._sync(method, model, params);
}
```

Comment: i would just like to ask where to put this kind of codes? on the view? i'm using backbone, underscore and required.js though. and how would i call it? because since the normal sync stringifies the model i need to stringify the stringified model.

Comment: you should keep this code in model ,backbone calls it automatically whenever there is GET,POST,PUT,DELETE requests,most of cases model.attributes.id doesn't work ,my case it works,need to check it

Comment: for stringifies check for parse method in backbone